# Is it possible to prevent sinatra/padrino from logging a request?

Tags: logging, sinatra, padrino

I'm looking for a way to prevent logging of health-check requests to my application. I can see that these projects are using Rack::CommonLogger, but I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation on ignoring certain requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a modular application try to split this part (i.e. part used for health check) to separate module and use something like that:

```
class NonLogged < Sinatra::Base
  configure :production, :development do
    enable :logging
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks, your helped me figure out how to do it for Padrino. I was expecting the answer to be the same for both since I was thinking it was a logger configuration question.

Answer (score 2):

Since I asked for a sinatra/padrino solution I thought I'd answer the question for padrino which I was able to figure out thanks to [Qatsi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625654/is-it-possible-to-prevent-sinatra-padrino-from-logging-a-request/13693516#13693516) sparking a more informed search.

In my `app/app.rb` I moved the healthcheck into its own application that looked something like this:

```
class MyApplicationHealth < Padrino::Application
  set :logging, false
  get(:index) { 'OK' }
end
```

And then in `config/apps.rb` I mounted that application at the healthcheck point like this:

```
Padrino.mount("MyApplicationHealth").to('/myapplicationhealthcheckuri')
```